# Add data to a list insde a list where item in the prerent list

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to select a where statement that adds items to a list where only product codes match. I have it so it gets all of the products sold in the sale but I would like there were statement to get only products in this sale.

PS: This is really hard to explain

Model

```
public class userSales
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public int Sale_Id { get; set; }
    public int CostumerID { get; set; }
    public string Sale_Date { get; set; }
    public string Paid { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Sale_Cost { get; set; }
    public string Discount_Code { get; set; }
    public List<SaleProduct> saleProductsList { get; set; }        
}

public class SaleProduct
{
    public int SaleID { get; set; }
    public string ProductCode { get; set; }
    public int ProductCount { get; set; }
    public string Image_Path { get; set; }
    public string Shoot_Date { get; set; }
    public string Shoot_Info { get; set; }
}
```

Linq statement where I'm having trouble:

```
var test = (from _ClientData in db.ClientDatas
                        join _salesInfo in db.Sales_Infoes
                        on _ClientData.CostumerID
                        equals _salesInfo.CostumerID
                        where _ClientData.UserName == _userName
                        select new userSales()
                        {
                            CostumerID = _ClientData.CostumerID,
                            Name = _ClientData.Name,
                            UserName = _ClientData.UserName,
                            Sale_Id = _salesInfo.Sale_Id, // This is the item i would like to use in my were statement
                            Sale_Date = _salesInfo.Sale_Date,
                            Sale_Cost = _salesInfo.Sale_Cost,
                            Discount_Code = _salesInfo.Discount_Code,
                            Paid = _salesInfo.Paid,

                            // Problem here
                            saleProductsList = db.SaleProducts.Where()
                        }).ToList();
```

Got to this based on the answer:

```
var reult = db.ClientDatas.Where(a => a.UserName == _userName)
              .Join(db.Sales_Infoes,
                    a => a.CostumerID,
                    b => b.CostumerID,
                    (a, b) => new userSales()
                    {
                        CostumerID = a.CostumerID,
                        Discount_Code = b.Discount_Code,
                        Sale_Cost = b.Sale_Cost,
                        Sale_Id= b.Sale_Id,
                        Name = a.Name,
                        Sale_Date = b.Sale_Date,
                        UserName = a.UserName,
                        Paid = b.Paid,
                        saleProductsList = db.SaleProducts.Where(c => c.SaleID == b.Sale_Id).ToList()
                    }).ToList();
```

Comment: It is very difficult to understand what you are asking.  Are you having trouble understanding the .Where() function?  have you tried db.SaleProducts.Where(c=>c.productId==SomeProductId)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not looking for a where, you're looking for a join. Where filters the results on a single table, join intersects two tables which is actually what you want here.

```
var result = db.Sales_Infoes.Where(x => x.UserName == _userName)
        .Join(db.ClientDatas,
        x => x.Sale_Id,
        y => y.Sale_id,
        (x, y) => new userSales() {
                // x is SalesInfo  obj y is ClientDatas obj do assignement here
            Name = y.Name,
            Sale_Date = y.Sale_date     
         }).ToList();
```

Just fyi I haven't had a chance to test that but it's the basic idea. You don't need a select like in your statement because the last argument I'm passing into join is the lambda `(x, y) => ...` in that case x and y are the current row from each table (that we've gotten from applying our where to the user sales table then joining those results into the salesproduct table) so whatever projections you want to do occur there. The other two method args above that are the telling join which fields to compare, it's the 'key selector' lambda expression for each table.